# How to get all nfts belonging to a collection on Solana?

Tags: metaplex, sol, solana-cli, web3.js, metaplex-js

Is there any easy way like a fetch request or something to get all nfts of a collection?

Comment: You can use Magic Eden's tool to retrieve NFTs hashes of a collection. Go to https://magiceden.io/mintlist-tool and use candy machine ID (usually the first creator of any NFT of the collection). Of course, this tool returns hashes of minted NFTs

Answer (score 2):

One possible way https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#candy-machines

Can go by `collection` member of the `PDA` too

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method:
Use [Pentacle Tools](https://pentacle.tools/nft-mints) with your CM ID.